# Sending attachments in embed field

Tags: discord

I'm working with discord.js and I was trying to get my bot to send attachments in an embed field. I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
    files: [ "images/twitter.png" ]
}});
```

I tried this too, it also didn't work:

```
message.channel.send({embed: {}, files: [ "images/twitter.png" ]}});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is at the bottom of a guide that I saw.

It should be like this:

```
    .setThumbnail("http://i.imgur.com/p2qNFag.png")
```

Hope this works for what you need to do.

Answer (score 7):

[This similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734519/how-to-use-local-file-as-thumbnail-in-discordjs-embedded-message) may help. Sending an attachment takes 2 steps.

Add the attachment to your message:

```
files: [{ attachment: 'images/twitter.png', name: 'twitter.png' }]
```

Then add the attachment to your embed:

```
image: { url: "attachment://twitter.png" }
```

Full example:

```js
message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    description: "This is some text",
    image: {
      url: "attachment://twitter.png"
    }
  },
  files: [{
    attachment: 'images/twitter.png',
    name: 'twitter.png'
  }]
});
```