# How to use local file as thumbnail in DiscordJS embedded message?

Tags: javascript, image, discord

Is it possible to use a local file as a thumbnail for an embedded message with DiscordJs?

```
"thumbnail": {
  "url": "../img/025.png"
},
```

This doesn't seem to work.

```
(node:34721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1):  
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body 
embed.thumbnail.url: Not a well formed URL.
```

Normal URL's do work however.

Comment: Send the proper url of the file. `https://example.com/img/025.png`

Comment: This was not an option for me. Some images were generated at the same moment, and they're not stored on any server. But I already got an answer :) (below).

Answer (score 7):

I've already found an answer.
Linking to the proper url of the file wasn't an option for me, because some images were generated.

You can attach an image to the message, and use this attachment as thumbnail.
Most basic example:

```js
const embed = {
  "title": "A Title" ,
  "color": 0xF96221,
  "thumbnail": {
    "url": "attachment://image.png"
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Field 1:",
      "value": "One",
      "inline": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Field 2:",
      "value": "Two",
      "inline": true,
    },
    {
      "name":"Field 3:",
      "value":"Three",
      "inline": true
    },
  ],
  "footer": {
    "text":"Footer text"
  }
};
```

Attach the image to the message with:

```js
message.channel.send({
  embed,
  files: [{
    attachment:'img/image.png',
    name:'image.png'
  }]
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same with discord webhook and this solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Other way to do, I hope it helps

```
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('fileRoute', 'nameOfYourPicture');
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Title')
  .setColor('#8fda81')
  .addField('Message Send', messageToSend)
  .attachFiles(attachment)
  .setThumbnail('attachment://nameOfYourPicture');
message.channel.send(embed);
```